# How to send a value from react-native to android activity?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to send a rowId from react native Listview to one of method in my android activity.the reason is I am integrating react to an existing android app. so for the time sake I wana send rowID for further process. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [React Modules Android](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) & [React Modules IOS](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

This is the only way to communicate with React component and native component.

You need to create a react method in module and use that to accept the value and send it across to native activity.

Comment: That make sense. But I am not sure, like in iOS we have some bridges for this?

Comment: @BaziPaleri We do have. Updated answer.

Comment: So we can call a method from component only right? Anyway I can call to my Activity