# Communication between react native and existing app Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use a fragment in react-native from my existing android application. I want to pass the data from my native side to react-native fragment. How to do it? What is the best way to it?

Comment: I answered this question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247882/how-to-send-a-value-from-react-native-to-android-activity/42248228#42248228 Modules are the only way you can achieve that

Comment: i think u r saying how to communicate from react to native which can be done with native modules. But am asking for how to communicate and send data to react fragment while calling for the fragment from native side